# how to save radio value with comma seperated in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i am getting radio buttons value in array after that i did this.

```
foreach ($get as $va) 
         {
             DB::table('user')->insert([
                ['uid' => $result, 'kid' => $id,'sid'=>json_encode(implode(',', $va))]
                ]);
         }
```

now i am getting this error:

```
implode(): Invalid arguments passed

data not getting saved why can anyone please help ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `foreach` here. If `$radio` is a simple array of values, do this:

```
DB::table('va')->insert([
    'uid' => $result,
    'vid' => $sid,
    'skid' => json_encode(implode(',', $va))
]);
```